# How to Hide iAD

Tags: iphone, ios4, iad

I would like to ask the following questions:

1) How to hide iAD when the user clicks on the empty screen?
2) How to identify inactivity i.e. If user has an opened some application and leave the iphone and went away and application remained open?

***Update:***

According the apple documentation, this method is responsible for dismissing the iAD. but this method is still not working in my code. Any sample or how this method works?

***- (void)cancelBannerViewAction***

*Explanation:*

A banner view action can cover your application’s user interface. However, your application continues to run, and receives events normally. If your application receives an event that requires the user’s attention, it can programmatically cancel the action and uncover its interface by calling cancelBannerViewAction. Canceling actions frequently can cause a loss of revenue for your application.

[Reference from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

But still I am unable to execute? This method is not working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do something like below code.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner 
{   
    if (!self.adBannerViewIsVisible) 
    {
         NSLog(@"\nBanner Success");
         [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
         // assumes the banner view is offset 50 pixels so that it is not visible.

         banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame,0,-94);       
         [UIView commitAnimations];

         self.adBannerViewIsVisible = YES;      
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error 
{   
      if (self.adBannerViewIsVisible)
      {
          NSLog(@"\nBanner Failed");
          [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];          

          banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 94);
          [UIView commitAnimations];

          self.adBannerViewIsVisible = NO;      
     }  
}
```

Just specify location of iAd in your code then you can change it's position by just changing value in this line

```
banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 94);`
```

Hope this may clear what you want.

Comment: I think the method *didFailToReceiveAdWithError* works when the AD is not able to received. i.e. on Airplane mode etc. But my question is how would I forcefully, dismiss the iAD once it appears?

Comment: For that you can just some logic when you want to hide iAd just make new method with code in side didFailToReceiveAdWithError method.

Comment: Actually, *didFailToReceiveAdWithError* is executed when you mobile is not able to get the ad either by any circumstances which are guniene. like no internet connectivity. My object is totally different. I donot wish to call *didFailToReceiveAdWithError*, I want to forcefully dismiss the AD and it would not be the proper way to dismiss the AD by calling it from *didFailToReceiveAdWithError*.

Comment: yes if you want to hide ad then please write code inside didFailToReceiveAdWithError within your another method and call them when you want to hide add

Comment: Hiding an iAd has nothing to do with *didFailToReceiveAdWithError*. I can just hide the iAd by calling *bannerView.hidden=YES*. This delegate method is very useful to take action when container fails to receive and iAd. It is not appropriate place for dismissing the iAd. Why not I use ***cancelBannerViewAction*** inspite of this! Since it is more appropriate rather than using ***didFailToReceiveAdWithError***