# Hide iAd in iOS 5

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, iad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Hide iAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909226/how-to-hide-iad)

I have currently a scenerio in which I have to show an iAd after certain amount of inactivity by the user. Once it appears after the inactvity, I want to hide the iAD again automatically after certain amount of time of the user activity. How to forcefully close or hide the iAd after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iAd is basically just a UIView you can call setHidden or change the alpha.

You can use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay to show your iAd after a certain amount of time, like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideAd:) withObject:nil afterDelay:3]
```

The same goes for hiding it.